# How do I restrict the calling of the constructor of one class to only its factory class?

Tags: c++, factory, friend

I want to prevent anything but the factory for my class from constructing objects of my class's type.  I need that class to have a public interface but I want to restrict the creation of it to only its factory.  How do I do that?

Let's call the class `Car` and the factory `CarFactory`.  Here is my initial idea of how to do this without using `friend` and exposing all the private members to the factory:

```
class Car {
private:
  Car();
  Car(Car& ref);

  friend class CarFactory;
};

class CarFactory {
public:
  Car * makeCar();
};
```

I found a related question for Java: [How do I make a constructor available to only the factory class?](/q/914727)

The code above works as is.  To clarify, I want to know if there is a way to share only the constructors with the factory and not all the private members?

Comment: That pretty much works as is. Whats the expected and observed behavior?

Comment: Just putting a question mark at the end of a statement doesn't make for a useful question?

Comment: It works as is, I was unsure if it was the right way to restrict access to only the factory class.  Is there a way to do this without exposing all the private members of the Car class to the CarFactory class?

Comment: I think `friend Car * CarFactory::makeCar();` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux where would I put that line of code?  Also, is that saying that makeCar is a friend but not other methods of CarFactory?  If so that's better than what I have now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comments, I assume you are looking for a friend function. Help on declaring friends can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend). Here is your example modified.

```
// Forward declare car
class Car;

class CarFactory {
public:
    Car * makeCar();
    Car * makeTruck();
};

class Car {
private:
    Car();
    Car(Car& ref);

    friend Car * CarFactory::makeCar();
};

Car * CarFactory::makeCar() {
    return new Car();
}

Car * CarFactory::makeTruck() {
    return new Car(); // Fails to compile
}
```

Edit: You asked in the comments for a solution where only Car's constructor is available to the factory. You will need to define a new utility class that's only usable by the method you want, then use that class for each method you want protected. I personally find this approach clunky, but it works.

```
class Car {

public:
    struct t_private{
    private:
        t_private() = default;
        friend Car * CarFactory::makeCar();
    };

    Car(t_private);

private:
    Car(Car& ref);
};

Car * CarFactory::makeCar() {
    return new Car(Car::t_private{});
}
```

Only `CarFactory` can construct a `Car` because nobody else can make a `Car::t_private` since it's constructor is private. `CarFactory` can not access private members of `Car` since it's not a friend.

Comment: I'm torn because this is intuitive and is useful yet not the restriction I asked about (which might not be possible).  I wanted to know if there was a way to only make available the constructor of Car to CarFactory.  This makes all private members of Car available to CarFactory::makeCar().

Comment: @tylerjw I'd go with the above, but... Insert another layer of abstraction. `Car` is friend of `CarFirewall`. `CarFirewall` contains only one method, which calls `Car` constructor. `CarFirewall` is friend of `CarFactory`... OK. Nevermind. François Andrieux just did pretty much this.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Car` an abstract class, and then implements it inside the factory as a private class:

```
class Car {
  public:
    virtual void drive()=0;
};
class CarFactory {
  private:
    class CarImp : public Car {
      ...
    };
  public:
    Car *makeCar() { return new CarImp(); }
}
```

Comment: While this is technically correct and would work as I asked by placing the constructor in an implementation that is private to the factory it seems unintuitive.  You are using the side affect of not being able to construct abstract objects and subclassing it as a private member of the factory.

Comment: This is not unintuitive, this is a good way to hide all implementations and let users only see interfaces. Generally considered as a good practice. It has the good advantage of not using friend relationship (which is problematic in many ways).